# How to console.log a promisified mongoose query *without* bluebird

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run a mongoose query and write it to the console without installing yet another library like bluebird. I have been unable to find this in the documentation.

Here is the query:

```
function activityH(){
        return setRecords.find({'item.title': 'marzipan'}
                                    , 'item.title item.quantity').exec();
    }
```

And the context in which I am calling it:

```
....[a bunch of promises].then(activityF).then(activityG).then(activityH).then(function(doc){console.log(doc);});
```

All of the prior activities are completing, but nothing is logging even though my query should have results. I feel this is a very basic question but I have looked for hours trying to find a solution and if this is a duplicate, the original answer is very hard to search for!

Do I absolutely need bluebird to do this? E.g. this [blog post](https://eddywashere.com/blog/switching-out-callbacks-with-promises-in-mongoose/)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a little logging function wrapper to help you out. Something like

```
function log(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

And then add it your `Promise` chain.

```
....[a bunch of promises]
   .then(log)
   .then(activityF)
   .then(log)
   .then(activityG)
   .then(log)
   .then(activityH)
   .then(log)
```

If you want some default messaging you could also pass a message string

```
function log(msg) {
    return function(data) {
        console.log(msg, data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

And then would add to the chain like:

```
activityA()
   .then(log('activityA'))
   .then(activityB)
   .then(log('activityB'))
```